# Process Control Block

Tags: operating-systems

As we know, the operating system maintains a data structure for every process called process control block. My question is where this data structure is stored inside the OS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not store something inside the OS. The OS is a program, or better a set of programs designed to manage a machine.
Same as any other program, the data used during execution are stored inside the RAM, at least during their use.
The OS interacts in a special way with a computer memory, having at his disposale a protected area inside wich sensible (from the OS point of view) data can be stored. The PCBs are stored inside this special area.